# How to set Custom layout for notification

Tags: android

I want to set notification in this form so how can i do it.Actually i have tried enough but not get success.please help

[image]

Comment: If it's urgent, StackOverflow is probably not the right place. Remember, this is not a forum or a help center.

Comment: Yes, thats true , First tell us what did you tried to get the result

Comment: okkkk.. thanks for suggestion  i have edited...

Comment: Instead of saying, "I have tried", I suggest you tell us what you've tried. Show us some code, tell us what you expected it to do, and what happened instead. It's best if you can provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!